# How to play a video on firefox mobile?

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile

I put a video as a header in my website. It looks quite OK on Chrome/Firefox desktop and Chrome mobile but... does not seem to work on firefox mobile.
I only see a fixed image on my video but the video does not play.

Is there something I can do ?

```
<video id="my_video" loop muted autoplay>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="my_video.mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the autoplay tag is not supported on mobile. That's to avoid users incurring data transfer costs because video files are large and can use up a lot of data.

you can use the 'poster' tag so when the video doesn't play you have an image.